# autoration not works with iOS6

Tags: ios, interface, rotation, ios6, uiinterfaceorientation

I would like that my UIViewController can auto rotate but just it, not any others uiviewcontroller. This UIViewController is presented into the UINavigationController which must not can auto rotate.
This code works with iOS 5 and 4 but not for iOS6.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return (YES);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return (YES);
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
}
```

thx for help :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to subclass your UINavigationController, implementing the rotation methods you have above in this subclass.  You can then conditionally return YES/UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll only when your rotatable view controller is visible, something like this:

shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:

```
if ([self.navigationController.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[MyRotatableViewController class]])
 return (YES);
else
 return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
```

supportedInterfaceOrientations:

```
if ([self.navigationController.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[MyRotatableViewController class]])
 return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
else
 return (UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
```

but again you have to do this in your Navigation Controller, not its child view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 6 only asks the "root-most" view controller about rotation.  That would have to be your UINavigationController (actually a subclass of such so you have someplace to put the rotation delegate methods), since the UINavigationController is under you other controllers.   Also make sure it is set as the window's root view controller.